# Selecting a column from a pivot table that has been reindexed in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'publisher': ['facebook', 'facebook', 'facebook', 'google', 'google', 'google'],
          'month_leadgen': ['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'],
         'month_payment': ['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'],
         'revenue': [60, 150, 450, 85, 250, 150]})
```

I then created a pivot table:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['publisher', 'month_leadgen'], columns='month_payment', values='revenue').reset_index()
```

I am trying to select the column `df['2020-01']` but I am receiving an error message:

> `KeyError: '2020-01'`

Can you help me understand why I cannot select this column? The df doesn't seem to be multi indexed. I cannot select any of the month columns but 'month_payment', 'campaign_name', and 'month_leadgen' can be selected no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `slice(None)` to select all the contents the level.  slice(None) exempts you from stating contents of the deeper level. it implies them

```
df=df.pivot_table(index=['publisher', 'month_leadgen'], columns=['month_payment'], values=['revenue']).reset_index()
print(df)



              publisher month_leadgen         revenue                
month_payment                         2019-01 2019-02 2019-03
0              facebook       2019-01    60.0     NaN     NaN
1              facebook       2019-02     NaN   150.0     NaN
2              facebook       2019-03     NaN     NaN   450.0
3                google       2019-01    85.0     NaN     NaN
4                google       2019-02     NaN   250.0     NaN
5                google       2019-03     NaN     NaN   150.0
```

**Selection**

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), '2019-01')]

 

               revenue
month_payment   2019-01
0                60.0
1                 NaN
2                 NaN
3                85.0
4                 NaN
5                 NaN
```

Comment: I received the following error when I tried your code: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: Because `df = df.pivot_table(index=['publisher', 'month_leadgen'], columns='month_payment', values='revenue').reset_index()` is different from `df=df.pivot_table(index=['publisher', 'month_leadgen'], columns=['month_payment'], values=['revenue']).reset_index()`

Comment: Ensure `columns`and and `values` are closed by corner brackets `[]` in your pivot equation